# Big Data Analytics using Redshift vs Spark, Oozie Workflow Scheduler with Redshift Analytics

Tags: apache-spark, analytics, bigdata, oozie, amazon-redshift

We want to do Big Data Analytics on our data stored in Amazon Redshift (currently in Terabytes, but will grow with time).

Currently, it seems that all our Analytics can be done through Redshift queries (and hence, no distributed processing might be required at our end) but we are not sure if that will remain to be the case in future.

In order to build a generic system that should be able to cater our future needs as well, we are looking to use Apache Spark for data analytics.
I know that data can be read into Spark RDDs from HDFS, HBase and S3, but **does it support data reading from Redshift directly?**
If not, we can look to transfer our data to S3 and then read it in Spark RDDs.

**My question is if we should carry out our Data Analytics through Redshift's queries directly or should we look to go with the approach above and do analytics through Apache Spark** (Problem here is that Data Locality optimization might not be available)?

In case we do analytics through Redshift queries directly, can anyone **please suggest a good Workflow Scheduler** to write our Analytics jobs with. Our requirement is to be able to execute jobs as a DAG (Job2 should execute only if Job1 succeeds, etc) and be able to schedule our workflows through the proposed Workflow Engine.

Oozie seems like a good fit for our requirements but it turns out that Oozie cannot be used without Hadoop. **Does it make sense to set up Hadoop on our machines and then use Oozie Workflow Scheduler to schedule our Data Analysis jobs through Redshift queries?**

Comment: These are good questions! But it's too much to tackle in one answer. I suggest breaking it up into smaller questions. Also, Stack Overflow is not the right place for opinion-based questions. "Does it make sense to..." is not a technical question that can be answered definitively. Such questions I think are better to ask on the user mailing lists of the involved projects. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access data stored on Redshift nodes directly (each via Spark), only via SQL queries submitted the cluster as a whole.

My suggestion would be to use Redshift as long as possible and only take on the complexity of Spark/Hadoop when you absolutely need it.

If, in the future, you move to Hadoop then Cascading Lingual gives you the option of running your existing Redshift analytics more or less unchanged.

Regarding workflow, Oozie is not a good fit for Redshift. I would suggest you look at Azkaban (true DAG) or Luigi (uses a Python DSL).